# Formatting of a long list

Tags: formatting

I've been writing LaTeX now for around 10 hours since my last post a couple of weeks ago. I think I'm getting the hang of it. I am finishing up a homework assignment and my document kind of looks cluttered. Is there a better way to indent long lists?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\textbf{6)} Suppose we roll a fair 6 sided die with the number [1,6] written on them. After the first die roll we roll the die $k$ times where $k$ is the number on the first die roll. The number of points you score is the sum of the face-values on all die rolls (including the first). What is the expected number of points you will score?

There are six different cases for the first roll 

\textbf{Case 1: Roll 1}
\begin{itemize}
    \item $P(D_1=1) =\frac{1}{6}$ 
    \item The expected number on the next roll is $E(D_2)=\frac{1}{6}\times(1+2+3+4+5+6)=3.5$
    \item $E(S_1) = 3.5+1=4.5$ points
\end{itemize}


\textbf{Case 2: Roll 2}

\begin{itemize}
    \item We know what the expected value of one roll is, and since rolling the die is independent we can use the previous expected value for the next roll.  
    \item $E(S_2) = (3.5\times 2)+2=9$ points
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Case 3: Roll 3}
\begin{itemize}
\item$E(S_3) = (3.5\times 3)+3=13.5$ points
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Case 4: Roll 4}

\begin{itemize}
    \item $E(S_4) = (3.5\times 4)+4=18$ points
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Case 5: Roll 5}

\begin{itemize}
    \item $E(S_5) = (3.5\times 5)+5=22.5$ points
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Case 6: Roll 6}

\begin{itemize}
    \item $E(S_6) = (3.5\times 6)+6=27$ points
\end{itemize}
Therefore, the expected number of points scored is
\begin{align}
    =\frac{1}{6}\times(4.5+9+13.5+18+22.5+27)=15.75 \notag
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this? A single `enumerate` with `itemize` inside it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\textbf{6)} Suppose we roll a fair 6 sided die with the number [1,6] written on them. After the first die roll we roll the die $k$ times where $k$ is the number on the first die roll. The number of points you score is the sum of the face-values on all die rolls (including the first). What is the expected number of points you will score?

There are six different cases for the first roll 

\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries Case \arabic*:},leftmargin=1.5cm]
\item Roll 1
\begin{itemize}
    \item $P(D_1=1) =\frac{1}{6}$ 
    \item The expected number on the next roll is $E(D_2)=\frac{1}{6}\times(1+2+3+4+5+6)=3.5$
    \item $E(S_1) = 3.5+1=4.5$ points
\end{itemize}


\item Roll 2

\begin{itemize}
    \item We know what the expected value of one roll is, and since rolling the die is independent we can use the previous expected value for the next roll.  
    \item $E(S_2) = (3.5\times 2)+2=9$ points
\end{itemize}

\item Roll 3
\begin{itemize}
\item$E(S_3) = (3.5\times 3)+3=13.5$ points
\end{itemize}

\item Roll 4
\begin{itemize}
    \item $E(S_4) = (3.5\times 4)+4=18$ points
\end{itemize}

\item Roll 5
\begin{itemize}
    \item $E(S_5) = (3.5\times 5)+5=22.5$ points
\end{itemize}

\item Roll 6
\begin{itemize}
    \item $E(S_6) = (3.5\times 6)+6=27$ points
\end{itemize}

\end{enumerate}

Therefore, the expected number of points scored is
\begin{align}
    =\frac{1}{6}\times(4.5+9+13.5+18+22.5+27)=15.75 \notag
\end{align}

\end{document}
```